# How do I prevent updates to nonexistent nodes?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I am using the REST api to PATCH nodes in my Firebase store. I would like to prevent updates to nodes that do not exist (because they were previously deleted). Right now, doing a PATCH to a nonexistent reference recreates it.

I looked into setting security rules, but newData.exists() does not discriminate between setting a new value and patching, so I couldn't figure out how to allow what I want without restricting new creations.

I can get a snapshot of the reference and check that before PATCHING, but I was hoping there was a more elegant way to do it without using two REST calls.

EDIT: some code!

My Firebase schema looks like:

```
requests:
    rq123:
        id: '123'
        sender: '1'
        recipient: '2'
        expiration: '1234567',
        filled: false,
        filledDate: '',
```

New requests are written from a mobile client. My server can make updates to those request entries using the REST api. Using the python-firebase library, that looks like:

```
request_ref = firebase_root + '/requests/' + request.id
patch_data = {
              'filled':'true',
              'filled_date':'7654321'
}

firebase_conn.patch(request_ref, patch_data)
```

Given the design of my app, I'd like to only perform that patch if the request entry still exists. It's clear that I can get a snapshot and perform the check that way before patching, but that seemed awkward to me.

Comment: How do you differentiate between a node that does not exist *yet* and a node that does not exist *anymore*? If you have no need for the distinction, you can check `data.exists()` in the security rules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - maybe I'm missing your point, but a rule like: ".write" : "data.exists()" will block writing new content (as well as blocking the updates, which I want). In fact, I do need to make the distinction. My app logic says "hey, update this existing thing before anyone sees it. Oh, it's already been deleted? Fine, nevermind then."

Comment: So you'll need a way to differentiate between data that does not exist *yet* and data that does not exist *anymore*. It is really difficult to provide an answer without seeing a sample of your data structure and of the calls you're doing. Please edit your question to include those. Also see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks a lot, Frank. I added the relevant code above. It sounds like this is more of an issue of my fundamental design and not about my ignorance to a particular piece of functionality. Nonetheless, if you have any recommendations on how to best handle, I'd love hear them :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I already remarked in the comments, there is no difference between these cases:

- Writing to a database location that doesn't exist **yet**
- Writing to a database location that doesn't exist **anymore**

So you will have to create that distinction in your application.

You have a few options. Not all of them apply to the REST API, but I'll mention them for completeness anyway.

### Transactional update

The Firebase SDKs (for JavaScript, Java/Android and iOS/OSX) have a method called `transaction`, which allows you to run a compare-and-set operation.

With that operation you could

```
ref.transaction(function(current) {
  if (current) {
    current.filled: true,
    current.filled_date:'7654321'
  }
  return current;
});
```

But since this method is not available on the REST API, it doesn't apply to your scenario.

### Mark deleted records

Alternatively you can mark deleted records, instead of actually deleting them:

```
requests:
    rq123:
        id: '123'
        sender: '1'
        recipient: '2'
        expiration: '1234567'
        filled: false
        filledDate: ''
        DELETED: true
```

You could also delete all the other properties when you pseudo-delete the request, i.e.

```
requests:
    rq123:
        DELETED: true
```

Then in your security rules, you can reject the write operation when this flag is present:

```
".write": "data.child('DELETED').val() != true"
```

There are many ways to flag the record. For example it seems like in your case, the record-node will always have an `id` property. So you could also simply leave the record-node as a marker, but remove *all* its properties:

```
requests:
    rq123: true
```

Since Firebase deleted nodes that don't have a value, I put `true` in here as the values.

With the above structure, we can only allow writes that either have an `id` property (which is the case when you create the request) or when an `id` property is already present (the PATH request from the REST API):

```
".write": "newData.child('id').exists() || data.child('id').exists()"
```

### Keep a list of deleted nodes

My final approach would be to keep a list of the deleted request keys:

```
requests:
    rq123:
        id: '123'
        sender: '1'
        recipient: '2'
        expiration: '1234567'
        filled: false
        filledDate: ''
deleted:
    rq456: true
    rq789: true
```

Once again, we set a dummy value of `true` for the deleted nodes to prevent Firebase from deleting them.

With this structure, you can reject write operations when the key you're writing to exists in the list of `deleted` requests:

```
".write": "!root.child('deleted').child(newData.key()).exists()"
```

Each approach has its own advantages and disadvantages, so you'll have to decide for yourself which one is best for your scenario.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to write this phenomenal answer. I went ahead and implemented your second suggestion. As a quick follow up - I wonder how you feel about this approach that basically uses permission rules as app logic? Do you consider it a valid design pattern to use permission rejections to make logic decisions (instead of just validating data)?

Comment: Good question. And unfortunately I don't have as clear-cut an answer to this one. My natural instinct would be to try and keep this logic out of the security rules, but that is definitely subjective.